# OpenGL-ES: How to set an object at the coordinates of the touch?

Tags: android, opengl-es, translation, touch-event

I'm looking for a way to have an opengl object(triangles etc) at the location on the screen where you touch the screen. I now have an 3D pyramid on the screen, wich moves over the screen, based on the difference between the start of your touch, and where you dragged it to.
In normal surfaceViews I could just do something like `element.x = event.getX()`, but this will not work in openGL. So anyone has an idea?
ps: i'm using java/Android.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OpenGL is nor like a surface view, where each element is persistent. It's the 3D equivalent to pens and brushes. You need to keep track of all data yourself.

So in your touch event handler you use the input coordinate to project a ray so some plane perpendicular to the view. You've to implement this projection yourself, but it's easy enough: Search for "ray plane intersection". This gives you the coordinates on the plane, that corresponds with that points projection on the screen where the user touched. You use this coordinates to transform the object and redraw the scene.

Comment: @user717572: What did you expect? Some magic OpenGL function that you give some screen coordinates and it would apply this to an object? This is not how OpenGL is designed. For one, OpenGL doesn't deal with "objects" (it has objects, but those are textures, shaders, i.e. resources required for drawing stuff, not the stuff to draw itself). You asked specifically about OpenGL, and my answer is: OpenGL does not deal with those things. You have to implement them YOURSELF, or use a library. And I exactly told you what to do: Project a ray into the scene, based on screen position, to a plane.